# Convert float color channels (R, G, B) to byte value

Tags: c++, colors, byte, rgb

I have implement a function that converts a float color channel (R, G, B) to a byte value.

> E.g.:
>   0.0f -> 0
>   1.0f -> 255

```
unsigned char RGBImage::convertColorChannel(float f) {

}
```

How can I get this results in C++?

Comment: static_cast<unsigned char>(255 * float value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return f * 255;`, the cast from `float` to `unsigned char` is implicit because of the return-type.

`return (f * 255) + 0.5;` to round the value correctly (since you are losing precision), but keep in mind that this is an extra calculation that will bring a performance hit. So if you are converting an entire high-resolution image, as the class name implies, then the additional calculation time may add up.

Answer (score 3):

Trivially (if you'll excuse the C-style cast):

```
return (unsigned char)(f * 255);
```

Note that this does *not* check whether `f` is correctly in the range `[0.0 - 1.0]`